# Can't Integrate Facebook SDK in phonegap Application

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

In CMD my exact Steps are

```
C://source/phonegap platform add android

C://source/phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="1043131165760698" --variable APP_NAME="somporko"
```

And then added App_invite code in a JS file and linked it in index.php

Then I imported android platform in android studio. It automatically added the gradle and plugin issues and fixed it. But while building I am getting error for the Facebook SDK 4 Plugin

```
Error:(8, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(9, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(10, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(11, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(12, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(13, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(14, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(15, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(16, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(17, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(18, 20) error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error:(19, 30) error: package com.facebook.appevents does not exist
Error:(20, 26) error: package com.facebook.login does not exist
Error:(21, 26) error: package com.facebook.login does not exist
Error:(22, 26) error: package com.facebook.share does not exist
Error:(23, 26) error: package com.facebook.share does not exist
Error:(24, 32) error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error:(25, 32) error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error:(26, 32) error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error:(27, 32) error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error:(28, 32) error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error:(29, 32) error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error:(30, 33) error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error:(31, 33) error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error:(32, 33) error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error:(33, 33) error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error:(69, 13) error: cannot find symbol class CallbackManager
Error:(70, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AppEventsLogger
Error:(75, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ShareDialog
Error:(76, 13) error: cannot find symbol class GameRequestDialog
Error:(77, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AppInviteDialog
Error:(78, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MessageDialog
Error:(754, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ShareLinkContent
Error:(772, 30) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookException
Error:(881, 55) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookRequestError
Error:(82, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable FacebookSdk
Error:(85, 42) error: package CallbackManager does not exist
Error:(88, 18) error: cannot find symbol variable AppEventsLogger
Error:(93, 74) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookCallback
Error:(93, 91) error: cannot find symbol class LoginResult
Error:(93, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable LoginManager
Error:(135, 27) error: cannot find symbol class ShareDialog
Error:(136, 59) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookCallback
Error:(136, 82) error: package Sharer does not exist
Error:(158, 29) error: cannot find symbol class MessageDialog
Error:(159, 61) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookCallback
Error:(159, 84) error: package Sharer does not exist
Error:(181, 33) error: cannot find symbol class GameRequestDialog
Error:(182, 65) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookCallback
Error:(182, 99) error: package GameRequestDialog does not exist
Error:(212, 31) error: cannot find symbol class AppInviteDialog
Error:(213, 63) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookCallback
Error:(213, 95) error: package AppInviteDialog does not exist
Error:(251, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable AppEventsLogger
Error:(257, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable AppEventsLogger
Error:(275, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable LoginManager
Error:(288, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable AccessToken
Error:(330, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable AppEventsLogger
Error:(373, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable AppInviteDialog
Error:(374, 29) error: package AppInviteContent does not exist
Error:(374, 68) error: package AppInviteContent does not exist
Error:(426, 18) error: cannot find symbol variable GameRequestDialog
Error:(435, 31) error: package GameRequestContent does not exist
Error:(435, 72) error: package GameRequestContent does not exist
Error:(448, 45) error: package GameRequestContent does not exist
Error:(448, 88) error: package GameRequestContent does not exist
Error:(456, 45) error: package GameRequestContent does not exist
Error:(456, 82) error: package GameRequestContent does not exist
Error:(466, 38) error: cannot find symbol class ShareLinkContent
Error:(466, 18) error: cannot find symbol variable ShareDialog
Error:(475, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ShareLinkContent
Error:(479, 38) error: cannot find symbol class ShareOpenGraphContent
Error:(479, 18) error: cannot find symbol variable ShareDialog
Error:(496, 33) error: package ShareOpenGraphObject does not exist
Error:(496, 82) error: package ShareOpenGraphObject does not exist
Error:(517, 33) error: package ShareOpenGraphAction does not exist
Error:(517, 82) error: package ShareOpenGraphAction does not exist
Error:(534, 34) error: package ShareOpenGraphContent does not exist
Error:(534, 78) error: package ShareOpenGraphContent does not exist
Error:(541, 40) error: cannot find symbol class ShareLinkContent
Error:(541, 18) error: cannot find symbol variable MessageDialog
Error:(550, 29) error: package ShareLinkContent does not exist
Error:(550, 68) error: package ShareLinkContent does not exist
Error:(590, 9) error: cannot find symbol class AccessToken
Error:(590, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable AccessToken
Error:(627, 9) error: cannot find symbol class LoginManager
Error:(627, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable LoginManager
Error:(709, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable LoginManager
Error:(747, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable LoginManager
Error:(750, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable LoginManager
Error:(755, 25) error: package ShareLinkContent does not exist
Error:(755, 64) error: package ShareLinkContent does not exist
Error:(769, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable AccessToken
Error:(779, 34) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookOperationCanceledException
Error:(782, 41) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookDialogException
Error:(804, 9) error: cannot find symbol class GraphRequest
Error:(804, 70) error: cannot find symbol variable AccessToken
Error:(804, 136) error: package GraphRequest does not exist
Error:(804, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable GraphRequest
Error:(854, 15) error: cannot find symbol class AccessToken
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 23.097 secs
Information:101 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: have you added facebook js in your index page ?

Comment: Yes. 
But that's not the thing. The plugin is not integrating with the android project at all...